# How to properly use EMF Databinding with a TreeViewer

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-emf

I would like to bind my EMF model to a `TreeViewer`. My Model looks like this:

```
Facility : Name
   - Part : Name 
       - SubPart : SubPartName
          - SubSubPart : SubSubPartName
          - SubSubPart : SubSubPartName
          - SubSubPart : SubSubPartName    
       - SubPart : SubPartName
  - Part : Another Name   
      - SubPart : SubPartName
```

I followed the Tutorial from Tom Schindl but I still do not understand how to implement the `TreeFactoryImpl`. So far it looks like this:

```java
@Override
public IObservable createObservable(Object target) {

    if (target instanceof IObservableList) {
        return (IObservable) target;
    } else if (target instanceof Facility) {
        IEMFListProperty multi = EMFProperties.multiList(ModelPackage.Literals.FACILITY__NAME);
        return multi.observe(target);
    } else if (target instanceof Part) {
        IEMFListProperty multi = EMFProperties.multiList(ModelPackage.Literals.PART__NAME);
        return multi.observe(target);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The problem is that only the facility is displayed. Which is now wonder since the `TreeStructureAdvisor` only seems to receive strings.

What I would like o accomplish is:

```
1.) Update the TreeViewrt if new nodes are added
2.) Update the name label if the name is changed
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here: [some googlecode](http://unicase.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6663/trunk/other/org.unicase.ui.web/src/org/unicase/ui/web/TreeView.java) this method looks different to what you are using.

```
private static class TreeFactoryImpl implements IObservableFactory {

    private IEMFListProperty multi = EMFProperties.multiList(
            WorkspacePackage.Literals.PROJECT_SPACE__PROJECT,
            MetamodelPackage.Literals.PROJECT__MODEL_ELEMENTS);

    public IObservable createObservable(final Object target) {
        if (target instanceof IObservableList) {
            return (IObservable) target;
        } else if (target instanceof ProjectSpace) {
            return multi.observe(target);
        } else if (target instanceof Project) {
            return multi.observe(target);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

From what I have seen there most example calls to the multilist are made with two lists. Is there a reason you are using that?

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
@Override
public IObservable createObservable(Object target) {

    if (target instanceof IObservableList) {
        return (IObservable) target;
    } else if (target instanceof Facility) {
        IEMFListProperty list = EMFProperties.list(ModelPackage.Literals.FACILITY__SUBPARTS);
        return list.observe(target);
    } else if (target instanceof SUBPART) {
        IEMFListProperty list = EMFProperties.list(ModelPackage.Literals.SUBPART__SUBPARTS);
        return list.observe(target);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The key here is to listen on the collection. This solves requirement 1 (Update the TreeView if new nodes are added)

After that I added a TreeLabelProvider as described in the blog Post from Tom Schindl.
This solves requirement 2 (Update the name label if the name is changed).